# Correctly handling ANSI escaped strings in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I use ANSI escaped strings in python 3/Ubuntu for printing e.g. colored text to the terminal. When I now try to find the "correct" length of such a string, this fails due to the fact that non printable "chars" get counted too, e.g.

`len('\x1b[35mtest string\x1b[0m')` is 25 even though the printable text's length only is 12.

I am hardly looking for a regex (if this could be suitable approach) that converts such a string into a list like so

`['\x1b[35m', 'test string', '\x1b[0m']`

The string could be more complex, e.g. multiple parts are colored, so the resulting list might get "longer"...

From there I would correctly calculate the length of such a string, and more importantly this would allow me to calculate a substring incl. resp. ANSI sequences like

`'\x1b[35mtest string\x1b[0m'[0:4]` --> `\x1b[35mtest\x1b[0m`

Thank you for any hint

Answer (score 0):

ansiwrap is you friend here - if you want an effective column width of `x` for string `s`, then `f'{s:{x+len(s)-ansilen(s)}}` will work